# Estimating powers like $1,000,000^{0.000001}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

I found a fun way to estimate powers like the above and am interested if there are even quicker ways.

> In the example given in the question start with $e^{(\ln 1,000,000)(0.000001)}$. Recognize that to a very good approximation, $(1 + 0.000001)^{1,000,000} = e$ and so we now have
>   $(1 + 0.000001)^{\ln(1,000,000)}$. But $\ln1,000,000$ is just $6\ln10=(6)(2.303)=13.818$. And because $(0.000001)(13.818)<<1$, the answer is very close to $1.000013818$.

Two simple approximations that one probably learned before calculus, but when combined in the right way can extend the range of mental calculation.

As I've asked, are there even quicker ways to compute such powers?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question.

Comment: @Rahul I believed the same thing when I first saw the question. That's why I edited it to include what the OP was actually asking (he's mentioned it in the very first line).

Answer (score 1):

$$1,000,000^{0.000\ 001}=\Big(10^6\Big)^{0.000\ 001}=10^{0.000\ 006}\simeq10^0=1.\quad$$